# Terminal auto-complete with @ symbol?

Tags: bash, shell, xterm

I have multiple directories that include the @ symbol within the directory name.  When I do the normal tab to auto-complete a directory name it chokes if there is an @ symbol included in the name; from that point on no directory auto-completion is available.

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it (i.e. you write `\@` instead of `@`)?

Comment: Doh! Thanks; I just slapped myself in the face for this one!  If you want the karma, post as an answer and I'll accept it.  I'm feeling pretty stupid over this...

Comment: @Tim the OP's last comment was directed to you.

Comment: @Terdon Thank you, I missed this. bigtunacan: Don't worry I felt the same after some of my questions...

Comment: It's just one of those situations where you hear the answer and think; wow that was so obvious why didn't I think to try that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some symbols have a special meaning in bash. If one wants to autocomplete a path or filename those must be escaped.

In your case this means that you must write `\@` instead of `@`.  Beside other symbols (like `\$` or `\\`) this is also the case for example spaces `\`.

For many symbols escaping is done automatically if one types at least one character behind the symbol before pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. For example if you have a file `abc@def`, then `abc@d` would expand to `abc\@def`

Comment: Maybe this varies depending on the platform.  I'm working on Mac OS X. Escaping like you mentioned works correctly.  However, if I don't escape and have additional characters `abc@def` this will not expand correctly, but the escaped version `abc\@def` will.

Comment: @bigtunacan Interesting, on my linux system it usually works except for backslashes and spaces. I assumed this to be standard.